# OneVsRest Classification why do the probabilites sum to 1?

Tags: python, classification, multilabel-classification, normalization

I am using OneVsRest Classifier in sklearn. So a multilabel model, 4 models for each class (i have 4 classes). When i called the predict_proba method i therefore get an array with 4 columns each one corresponding to a probability for that class. e.g.

```
0     1     2     3 
0.6  0.2   0.1   0.1 
0.8  0.05  0.05  0.1
```

I know the models all train independently of one another and that the class asigned i.e. whether 0 1 2 3 takes the argmax of the 4 . what else happens under the hood with multilabel classifation such that each row sums up to 1? Why and how is this normalization happening.

Comment: Did you have a look on the ground based paper from by Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani in 1998? https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-26/issue-2/Classification-by-pairwise-coupling/10.1214/aos/1028144844.full

Comment: No i have not seen this

Comment: @NicolasMartin, at least the first page of that paper seems to suggest that it's about one-vs-one modeling rather than one-vs-rest?

Comment: Don't confuse [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) (every instance has exactly one class) with [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) (an instance can have any number of classes, from 0 to all of them). One-vs-rest is the standard method used for multiclass classification, it's not relevant for multi-label. Apparently you want to use multi-label but you're currently using multiclass.

Comment: Ok well lets call it muticlass then

Comment: I was also going to point out the difference between multi-label classification.  But @Erwan, if the sklearn probabilities sum to 1, OP is probably actually doing a multiclass classification.

Comment: @Maths12 Ok, I thought you meant to use multi-label. By definition in multi-class the predicted probabilities are **not** independent, since the goal is to predict the most likely class among all the possible classes.

Comment: @Erwan but in OneVsRest does it not train the models indepndently? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html <-- under the hood it converts the target y into binary columns which is what i have done hence why i thought it was multilabel

Comment: @Maths12 I see the confusion, I will try to explain this point in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification), the assumption is that every instance has exactly one class. Example: a poll asks people their favourite colour among blue (B), yellow (Y) or red (R). Each instance represents a person's answer, either B, Y or R. The "one vs. rest" method means that 3 binary classifiers are trained:

- "B" vs "not B", where the Y and R instances are labelled "not B"
- "Y" vs "not Y", where the B and R instances are labelled "not Y"
- "R" vs "not R", where the B and Y instances are labelled "not R"

These models are not independent by assumption, for example:

- if the class is B then it cannot be Y or R.
- if the class is not Y then it's either B or R.
- Etc.

In probabilistic terms this translates as a distribution which sums to 1, because if a class has a high probability then it's impossible that any other class also has a high probability (complement). This is why the probabilities predicted by the binary classifiers are each divided by the sum (see [Ben's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/102175/64377) for details).

Note: by contrast [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) allows every instance to have any number of classes. In the example above it's as if the poll asks people to say whether they like each colour B, Y, R. A person might like all 3 colours or none of them. This implies that the binary classifiers are independent:

- For "B vs not B", both the B and "not B" classes can contain instances which also have Y or R (or both).
- As a consequence the classifiers are independent: knowing that an instance has class B doesn't imply anything about the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

The normalization is straightforward division by the sum of the probabilities: [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/multiclass.py#L420).

As to *why*, it's obviously desirable to have a sum of 1, but beyond that it's perhaps subjective.  There's a discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/6665/232706) suggesting that simple normalization outperformed other aggregations, but if I'm reading the linked paper correctly, it was a marginal gain and inconsistent across other calibration methods and datasets.  I also like the [answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210690/232706), which emphasizes that for any of this to make sense you need reasonably well-calibrated individual model predictions, and in that case the sum should be close to 1 already.